# What's the difference between calling a function and returning a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

I'm using the checkForm function to validate a simple form. When the user press submit, run checkForm. What's the difference between the first and second example?

Example 1.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    checkForm();
});
```

Example 2.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    return checkForm();
});
```

Comment: What `checkForm()`is returning?

Comment: In an event handler you can return `true` or `false`, the latter combines `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation` in jQuery, stopping the form submission, so if the `checkForm()` function returns `false`, the form is not submitted, if it returns `true` the form is submitted etc.

Comment: In example 2, you're not returning a function, you're returning the result of executing the function. Returning a function would look like this: `return checkForm;`. Of course, that doesn't make sense in this case, but I think the distinction is important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the second example you're not actually returning *the function* but rather *the result* of having executed the function.  (Considering the execution of code from right-to-left in this case.)

To illustrate, change your first example slightly:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var result = checkForm();
});
```

As you can see, the function is executed and a result is returned from the function.  It's just that nothing is ever done with that result.  It immediately falls out of scope as the anonymous function completes, fading into antiquity.

Slightly modify the second example to further illustrate:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var result = checkForm();
    return result;
});
```

Just as with the first example, `checkForm` is executed and its result stored in a variable.  Then that value is returned from the anonymous function.  Naturally, this process can be in-lined such that the temporary variable isn't needed:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    return checkForm();
});
```

The order of operations doesn't change, `checkForm` is executed, returns a result, and that result is returned from the anonymous function.

You *could* return the function itself, having not actually executed it:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    return checkForm;
});
```

Since functions are "first-class citizens" in JavaScript and can be passed around like any other variable, this would return an actual function and not the result of the function.  It would be assumed that calling code would probably end up executing the function.  However, in this case (a `submit` handler), that of course wouldn't make sense, as it's expecting a boolean value and not a function.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it really clarifies the differences.

Comment: Absolutely. Thanks for this great answer. Helped me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The main difference in your code is that in first case you just run validation and in second case if your validation returns Boolean value you will prevent form submission.

So in first case your form will be submitted every time, even if `checkForm()` will return `false`. In second case if `checkForm()` will return `true` your form will be submitted, and if it will return `false` it will prevent form submission.

So basically assume `checkForm()` returning `false`, your function will look in first example as:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    false;
});
```

and in second example:

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so I noticed. But how come the checkForm function doesn't take care of this by itself? How come we have to return the function in order to prevent submitting in case of a false value?

Comment: You don't return the function in your example, you are returning function result. So if you add `()` to your function name it will be  just invoked. And even if you have inside of that function `return` statement this will not prevent form submission untill you will have `return` statement in `submit` method.